# Searching tables without model in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table for messages (without a controller and model) that users can submit a message to the admin. Aside from creating a messages model and then using loadmodel to search it, is there a better way of doing this?

I would just do something like

```
//AdminsController
$this->loadmodel('Message');
$this->Message->find(....);
```

While that is easy to do, I feel like creating a messages model isn't necessary if I can set something up in the Admin model to allow me to do so. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A model *file* isn't necessary

Cake [will use an AppModel instance](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#understanding-models) if a model is requested for which there is no model file found. If a model has no associations and [follows conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) (plural name, primary key field `id`) - then it's not necessary to create a model file at all.

As such the example code in the question will "just work".

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea. Thank you